# Save recorded video only when 'Save' button is clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm able to record videos and perform playback on my app using the codes below:

```
- (IBAction)recordVideo:(id)sender {

 if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
 }
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    self.videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

   self.videoController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];

  [self.videoController setContentURL:self.videoURL];
  [self.videoController.view setFrame:CGRectMake (0, 40, 320, 385)];
  [self.view addSubview:self.videoController.view];

  [self.videoController play];
}
```

I'm also aware that the video can be saved upon playback using:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

  NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
  if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.movie"]){
    // Saving the video / // Get the new unique filename
  NSString *sourcePath = [[info  objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"]relativePath];
    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(sourcePath,nil,nil,nil);
}
```

But how do I **save the video with a different button action** (for example:'Save Video') ?

Answer (score 1):

Upon completion of the video recording or picking process, the `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` method of the `UIImagePickerController` is giving you the path to the video, which is temporary path (your `sourcePath` string in your implementation). So, what you do is,

1) remove `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(sourcePath,nil,nil,nil);` to avoid saving the video right after recording;

2) Copy or move the video file to another path, maybe to `Documents` or `temp` directory within the app's sandbox, and store/save that path;

3) When user taps the save button, save your video to the Photos using `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(videoPath,nil,nil,nil);` (`videoPath` is the path where you have copied/moved your video file).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Appreciate your explanation about the **sourcePath**. What should I include in '- (IBAction)saveVideo:(id)sender' in order to the call the method?

Comment: You should include the actual video saving code in that method.